# scrapy fails to crawl craigslist

Tags: scrapy, rules, web-crawler

This same code crawls yellowbook with no issues and as expected. Change the rule over to CL and it hits the first url and then teeters out with no relevant output.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigs.items import CraigsItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "craigs"
        allowed_domains = ["craiglist.org"]

        start_urls = ["http://newyork.craigslist.org/cpg/"]

        rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/blockquote[3]/p/a',)), follow=True, callback='parse_profile')]

        def parse_profile(self, response):
                found = []
                img = CraigsItem()
                hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
                img['title'] = hxs.select('//h2[contains(@class, "postingtitle")]/text()').extract()
                img['text'] = hxs.select('//section[contains(@id, "postingbody")]/text()').extract()
                img['tags'] =  hxs.select('//html/body/article/section/section[2]/section[2]/ul/li[1]').extract()

                print found[0]
                return found[0]
```

Here is the output  http://pastie.org/6087878
As you can see, it has no issue getting the first url to crawl  http://newyork.craigslist.org/mnh/cpg/3600242403.html>
but then dies.

I can use the CLI and dump all the links like this  SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/blockquote[3]/p/a',)).extract_links(response)  with xpaths or keyword  SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'/cpg/.+').extract_links(response)
output ->  http://pastie.org/6085322

but in the crawl, the same query fails. WTF??

Comment: A tcpdump packet capture, when comparing the CLI action with 'does' recover the data, to the crawl action which does 'not' recover the data. You can clearly see that craigslist 'is' giving up the data. Following the GET, I recieve plenty of http data from the URL. But scrapy doesn't do anything with it, in the crawl. This 100% looks like a scrapy/(user) side error. I am stuck.  http://tinypic.com/r/289lw9/6   http://tinypic.com/r/2dugcj/6

Comment: The script is run and performs the first GET of the start URL and the data is received from CL, as expected.
But, there is never a second GET request that even leaves the NIC despite what scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor is saying in the debug.  
[craigs] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'newyork.craigslist.org': <GET http://newyork.craigslist.org/lgi/cpg/3576532314.html>
Scrapy says it happens, but tcpdump tells a different story.

Comment: My parse 'does' work. But data collection is never executed??

Comment: http://pastie.org/6089422

Answer (score 3):

if you look in documentation you will see

> allowed_domains An optional list of strings containing domains that
>   this spider is allowed to crawl. Requests for URLs not belonging to
>   the domain names specified in this list won’t be followed if
>   OffsiteMiddleware is enabled.

your allowed domain is

```
 allowed_domains = ["craiglist.org"]
```

but you are trying to fetch a subdomain

```
02-07 15:39:03+0000 [craigs] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'newyork.craigslist.org': <GET http://newyork.craigslist.org/mnh/cpg/3600242403.html>
```

that is why it is filtered

either remove `allowed_domains` from your crawler of add proper domains in it for avoiding filtered offsite requests

Comment: @user1544207 dont forget to accept the answer so that other can get benefit from this post (can accept this answer by clicking on tick mark bellow upvote sign)